# Assigning values in a column to deciles when breaks are not unique

Tags: r, quantile

Assume that I have a vector with 1000 numbers in it. I want to obtain the deciles of this vector and then find the mean of each decile. However, there are 215+ zeros in this vector. Meaning that the first and second breaks will be zero, thus I will run into `Cut() error - 'breaks' are not unique` error. What I want is to assign 100 zeros to the first decile, another 100 to the second decile and the last 15 zeros to the third decile. Such that the mean of the first and second deciles will be zero. Here is a reproducible and smaller example with the similar problem:

```
v=c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 6, 3, 7)
cut_q10 <- quantile(v, probs = seq(0, 1, 0.1))
v_q10 =cut(v, breaks = cut_q10,labels = FALSE)
#Error in cut.default(v, breaks = cut_q10, labels = FALSE) : 
#  'breaks' are not unique
```

What I would like to obtain is:

```
v_q10 = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,10,9,10)
```

or

```
v_q10 = c(2,2,1,1,3,4,4,3,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,10,9,10)
```

etc...
All of them are acceptable as long as there is two 0's in the first decile, two 0's in the second, two 1's in the third, two 1's in the fourth etc. etc. such that regardless of which `v_q10` is obtained when I find the means of each decile I attain this :

```
merged = as.data.frame(cbind(v,v_q10))
merged = merged%>%group_by(v_q10)%>%summarise(means = mean(v))

   v_q10 means
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1   0  
# 2     2   0  
# 3     3   1  
# 4     4   1  
# 5     5   1  
# 6     6   2  
# 7     7   2  
# 8     8   3  
# 9     9   4  
#10    10   6.5
```

I know that it is possible to achieve this by writing a long code but I was wondering if there is a function or a code of a few lines that can achieve this. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `dplyr::ntile`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
cut(rank(v, ties = "first"), 10, lab = FALSE)
## [1]  1  1  2  2  3  3  4  4  5  5  6  6  7  7  8  8  9 10  9 10
```

Alternatives include using `ties = "last"` or using `ties = "random"` or using `order(order(v))` in place of `rank(...)`.

Comment: thanks a lot this works great. I was wondering one more thing. Can I do the same thing if i wasn't given the vector v explicitly but as a data frame of each value and its weight next to it, as in: `v = data.frame(values=c(0,1,2,3,5,6,7),weights=c(4,6,4,3,1,1,1))

Comment: If by weight you mean that that value is to repeated that number of times then first form: `v <- with(DF, rep(values, weights))`